# How to use an array created with Jinja2 in an ansible task?

Tags: ansible

When creating a VM in the vCenter using vmware_guest, we want to use an array to control the number and size of the disks to be created in the VM.

The Arrey:

```
vm_disk_gb:
  - sda: 50
  - sdb: 30
  - sdc: 50
```

And here the output we like to have:

```
        disk:  
        - size_gb:   "{{ vm_disk_gb[sda] | default(50) }}"
          type:      "eagerzeroedthick"
          datastore: "s1p1d2-vSAN"
        - size_gb:   "{{ vm_disk_gb[sdb] | default(50) }}"
          type:      "eagerzeroedthick"
          datastore: "s1p1d2-vSAN"
        .....
    networks:
```

We tryed:

```
vmware_guest_disks: "[{
(% for vm_disk in {{ vm_disk_gb }} %)
'size_gb':'{{ vm_disk_gb[vm_disk] | default(50) }}',
'type': 'eagerzeroedthick'.
'datastore': 's1p1d2-vSAN'
(% endfor %)}]"
```

and:

```
   disk: "{{ vmware_guest_disks }}"
   networks:
```

But did not work.

Comment: *vm_disk_gb* must be a dictionary if you want to reference the disks  `vm_disk_gb[sda]`

Comment: You are mixing the usage of a list `for vm_disk in vm_disk_gb` with the usage of the dictionary `vm_disk_gb[vm_disk]`. You have to decide what you want.

Comment: What is the purpose of the default options if the size is always declared in `vm_disk_gb`?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, the playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  
  vars:
    vm_disk_gb:
      - sda: 50
      - sdb: 30
      - sdc: 50
      # That one is just to test default is working
      - empty_disk:

    disk: |-
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for vm_disk in vm_disk_gb %}
      - size_gb: "{{ vm_disk.values() | first | d(50, true) }}"
        type: "eagerzeroedthick"
        datastore: "s1p1d2-vSAN"
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: disk
```

gives as a result:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "disk": [
        {
            "datastore": "s1p1d2-vSAN",
            "size_gb": "50",
            "type": "eagerzeroedthick"
        },
        {
            "datastore": "s1p1d2-vSAN",
            "size_gb": "30",
            "type": "eagerzeroedthick"
        },
        {
            "datastore": "s1p1d2-vSAN",
            "size_gb": "50",
            "type": "eagerzeroedthick"
        },
        {
            "datastore": "s1p1d2-vSAN",
            "size_gb": "50",
            "type": "eagerzeroedthick"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```